# How to use IF with dates by month, excluding specific days

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use an excel formula to see if an input date's month is `<=` today's month by a maximum of 3 (irrespective of day).
The input `DAY` must also `NOT` be `>=` today's date by a maximum of 10.
Then provide a `YES` or `NO` output.

I'm relatively new to excel (and coding in general), but I have managed to have it specify if a month is `<=` to today's month.

But I have hit a wall when it comes to the extra rules above.

Perhaps using two separate `IF` statements for the `DAY` and `MONTH` rules would be easiest, then using an `IF AND` to join them up in the output cell. I'm just unsure how to put the limiters on the `<=` and `>=` operators.

```
=IF(MONTH(A2)<=MONTH(A4),"YES","NO")
=IF(DAY(A2)>=DAY(A4),"YES","NO")
=IF(B8 AND B9 = "YES","YES","NO")
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:

> Today: 11/04/2019
>
> Input: 10/01/2019
>
> OUPUT: YES

(Input month is less than today's month by 3 months, input day is not equal to or greater than today's day)

> Today: 11/04/2019
>
> Input: 20/01/2019
>
> OUPUT: NO

(Month is within 3 months **BUT** the day is `>=` today's day)

Comment: You should look for `AND` and `OR` functions along with the `IF` statement, that is what you need.

Comment: Must iit be calendar months or could you use 91 days as a substitute for 3 months?

Comment: @HarassedDad Yeah, it must be calendar months. I'm onto something with the MONTH(cell) bit, I'm sure. But I don't know how to limit by a specific number range

Comment: I don't get the day part. If the date is 2 months ago but 10 days after today's what happens?

Comment: @Damian Yeah I get you, but I don't know how to use AND or OR statements to limit the results to specific amounts of calendar months 
eg: <= 3 months before today's month but not 4 months

Comment: @Damian so think of the numbers separate from one another. 
As long as the month is within 3 calendar months prior to todays month
and the day is not the same calendar day as today or 10 days ahead then it needs to output True or Yes

Comment: @MdeRNier Check my answer, I'm not sure if i got your needs right but I've explained the logic so it shouldn't be hard to fit as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

`=IF(AND(MONTH(C15)>=MONTH(E2)-3;MONTH(C15)<=MONTH(E2));IF(AND(DAY(C15)>=DAY(E2);DAY(C15)<=DAY(E2)+10);"YES";"NO");"NO")`

At least it did on my worksheet.

The logic behinds is: First check if the month is equal or greater than today's month `AND` if its equal or lesser than today's month - 3. If that's not true it just skips to the las `"NO"`. Now let's say the first check returns `YES`then again, check if the day is equal or greater than today's day `AND` is lesser or equal than today's day + 10.

Edit: Since you are toying with Months as numbers you will have a hard time when 3 months means last year. The only way to sort this is going to dates instead months.